# jQuery, check for dynamic created checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a table with a list of check boxes with values reading out of JSON file.

Every time a check box is clicked i want to execute the function count checked. Unfortunately JQuery `$("input[type=checkbox]")` doesn't recognize the dynamic created check boxes. The only check box working is the one written directly in body code block.

How can I say JQuery to check for newly created check boxes?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#get").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("data.txt",function(result){
            $("#b").append('<form><table></table></form>');
            $.each(result['effectNames'], function(i, field){
                $("table").append('<tr><td>' + field + '</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="' + i + '" ></td></tr>');
                });
            });
    });
    var countChecked = function() {
      var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
      $( "#a" ).text( n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" );
    };
    countChecked();
    $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="get">Get JSON data</button>
    <input type="checkbox" name="r" value="Hourly" checked="checked">
    <div id="b"></div>
    <div id="a"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is because you only bind the function `countChecked` to the checkboxes on document loading. If you create a new checkbox after it. The function is not bound to the checkbox (because it's a new checkbox).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use event delegation here

```
$("#b").on( "click", "input[type=checkbox]", countChecked );
```

Comment: By far the cleanest way to do it :) I suggest explaining to the OP what's happening here.

Comment: you should reduce the scope to $("#b#").on( "click", "input[type=checkbox]", countChecked );